# Table with "TIME" column could not be accessed from Python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql-9.3

I have a table in Postgres with a column name as TIME(UpperCase). 
While inserting csv into this table from Postgres itself using SQL command is easy.

```
COPY american_district FROM 'O:\Python\PostGREsql\district.csv' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER AS ',' NULL AS '\N';
```

but inserting the same csv into the table using python code below gives me an error as

```
f = open('O:\Python\PostGREsql\district.csv')
cur_DBKPI.copy_from(f, 'american_district', sep=',', null='')
```

ERROR:

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for type date: "TIME"
CONTEXT:  COPY american_district, line 1, column time: "TIME"
```

I found that its best practice to keep the column in lower case but is there any workaround of it?

Comment: That error indicates that your Python code thinks the first line is data, not the header. And thus it sends the value `TIME` to be inserted into that column - which obviously isn't going to work.  It has nothing to do with UPPER or lower case column names. You need to pass the equivalent of the `HEADER` option to that Python method. (Note that the [name of the database](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_PostgreSQL.3F_How_is_it_pronounced.3F_What_is_Postgres.3F) is either Postgres or PostgreSQL. It's **not** PostGREsql or PostGre or PosGreSQL)

Comment: @Horse With No Name : Thanks for the feedback shared. I got the issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by changing the syntax of my query to add header in it using "copy_expert".

```
f = open('O:\Python\PostGREsql\district.csv')
sql = "COPY american_district FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER AS ',' NULL AS '\\N'"
cur_DBKPI.copy_expert(sql=sql,file=f)
```